# Reverse Geocode in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have coordinates that I'm trying to get the address for.  In Windows Phone 8 Silverlight apps, I used to use ReverseGeocodeQuery to get the address but that doesn't seem to be supported in WinRT.

What is the proper way to do this in WinRT, is there something similar that I should use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `MapLocationFinder`. Here is a code fragment that I'm frequently using. What it basically does is to issue a query to the MapLocationFinder and checks if the search was successful. Then I take the first location and check if `Town` is set.

You can of course also foreach over `result.Locations` and inspect every element if you'd like to.

```
public static async Task<MapLocation> resolveLocationForGeopoint(Geopoint geopoint)
{
    MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(geopoint);
    if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
    {
        if (result.Locations.Count != 0)
            // Check if the result is really valid
            if (result.Locations[0].Address.Town != "")
                return result.Locations[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```